# requests cannot get img while Chrome browser can

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests

This code

```
response = requests.get('https://ec.ef.com.cn/partner/englishcenters', headers=headers)

filename = 'quotes.html'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

gets me a 'quotes.html' on my laptop.

Here is part of it

```
<div class="etc-login-captcha">
    <input type="hidden" id="CaptchaId" name="CaptchaId" disabled />
    <input class="etc-login-input" tabindex="5" id="CaptchaCode" name="CaptchaCode" type="text" placeholder="验证码" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="false" data-msg-minlength="请至少输入 {0} 个字符。" disabled />
    <img src="about:blank" class="etc-login-captcha-img" title="click here to refresh verification code" />
</div>
```

which clearly shows the  is just a placeholder.

While accessing the same url with Chrome browser can get the actual image src.

How do I have requests get the actual image src?

---

Here is the comparison

what scrapy gets

```
<input type="hidden" id="CaptchaId" name="CaptchaId" disabled />
```

what Chrome browser gets

```
<input type="hidden" id="CaptchaId" name="CaptchaId" value="xx9615xx-29F6-4665-A0C2-xxA8230731xx">
```

Comment: sounds like it's modified with javascript at runtime.  you'll need a more sophisticated scraper that can run rudimentary JS.  Or you'll have to scrape whatever variable (whether it is populated by an XHR api request or just embedded server side, or if you're lucky generated client side, so you might not even need to scrape it) directly.  Given that it's a captcha I would hazard a guess it is designed to not be easy to scrape.

Comment: @user120242 Thank you. Could it be done with scrapy or requests?

Comment: It's generated at runtime using Math.uuid.  It's just a unique identifier, so it can identify you across multiple requests (while on the same page).  There probably isn't much purpose to scraping it, as it is arbitrarily created at runtime: https://ec.ef.com.cn/partner/_scripts/ec/main.js?hotfix=2&siteversion=26-1 line 390

Comment: Seems it's dynamically loaded as @user120242 mentioned. I would give [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) a try.

Comment: @Moe Thank you. To run pyppeteer, I need to have chromium installed first, right?

Comment: @JJJohn I'm pretty sure you don't need to run pyppeteer for this after reading their code.  It's just a uuid.  It looks like you could even feed your own fake uuid if you wanted to.  It's just using this: https://ec.ef.com.cn/_scripts/math.uuid.js

Comment: @JJJohn most welcome. It will install automatically the first time you run it. But i think `user120242` is on point, i didn't notice the JS file he has referenced.

Answer (score -1):

Server response without `src` attribute, and probably it adds on client side by JavaScript.

So, you should use something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)